# position of conditional parameters does matter in execution time?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database table with more than 3.5 million rows where I need to find active user (`bit` column) where the name contains `ar` in firstname column (`nvarchar(100)`).

I have not implement any index's over `firstname`.

I wrote a query like:

```
select * 
from table 
where IsActive = 1 and firstname like '%ar%'

Time taken: ~17s
```

and a second one like this:

```
select * 
from table 
where firstname like '%ar%' and IsActive = 1

Time taken: ~2s
```

I don't get what is going on behind the scenes. Can please some one explain how SQL Server 2008 R2 take this?

What other things should I keep in mind while implementing such conditions?

Comment: If `firstname` is a `nvarchar`, you should use an `N` prefix on your string literals! Use: `... WHERE firstname LIKE N'%ar%' ..` to make clear this is a Unicode string literal. Otherwise, you'll incur an implicit conversion (which also costs some time)

Comment: In this case, most likely, you ran query #1, and then query #2 right after that- right? So that pages that SQL Server needs to search where already in memory -> therefore it's a lot faster. I'm pretty sure, if you run query #2 against a "cold" SQL Server (stop & restart the SQL Server service, then run this query #2) it'll be 17 seconds, too.

Comment: so you mean, it doesn't matter where i put conditions in query ?

Comment: If you have **no indexes** - no there should be more difference in which order you have your `WHERE` conditions. SQL Server's query optimizer is free to reorder those conditions anyway....

Comment: Choose the most readable order to express the condition. Since you're asking for active users you should start with `IsActive`. That has nothing to do with efficiency.